# Signal Convolution in C++ like Python np.convolve

Tags: python, c++, numpy, numerical-methods

I am writing a numerical simulation code where a convolution of a signal and a response function is needed (full mode). Now this sounds like a standard problem and I have used `np.convolve` etc. in python to great effect.

However, given that I need a faster computation (this convolution needs to be performed millions of times per simulation), I have started to implement this in C++, but I have struggled to find a analogue of `np.convolve` or `scipy.fftconvolve` in C++, where I would just plug in two `std::vector<double>` arrays and get the result of the discrete convolution. The only thing remotely resembling what I need is the implementation of a convolution from [Numerical Recipes](https://github.com/blackstonep/Numerical-Recipes/blob/master/convlv.h), however comparing to the numpy results this implementation seems to be just wrong.

**So my question boils down to: Where can I find a library/code that performs the convolution just like the Python implementations do? Surely there must be some already exisiting, fast solution.**

Comment: There is fastest fourier transform of the west library FFTW. Then you take fft of input, fft of filter, multiply the outputs, inverse-fft the result. This makes convolution. But you may require transforming the origin first, depending on the problem.

Comment: Ok, that is a good suggestion, however I really wonder why there is not a single usable convolution library, whereas in Python there seem to be dozens.

Comment: Convolution alone is too simple, its just polynomial multiplication. You would have to look for a signal processing library. If the filter is short and the signal long, then the FFT method is best applied in an overlap-add scheme.

Comment: Even if problem is 3D, you can still use 1D FFT but separately for every pencil in the cube. It just requires same thing N x N times per dimension (for N x N x N cube).

Comment: @Iconstrife I'm sure there are a lot of libraries, check out for instance diplib: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/222b57197c08df6bef67a549b39d8afa2d74b34b/dipimage/private/dip_filtering.cpp But maybe you should ask about the differences of the python and your numerical recipes implementation, a naive convolution usually is not that bad when it comes to accuracy.

Comment: Yeah I have a "naive implementation" already, just the typical two nested loops. However, my simulation experiences a bad blowup due to something in the convolution. Not sure what. Comparing to python shows that the python implementation of the convolution is much "smoother" and does not lead to a unpyhsical explosion...

Comment: Check the direction of the filter in your implementation. It should be the "mathematical" convolution `sum c[k]*x[n-k]`. One often finds also implementations with `sum c[k]*x[n+k]`. This is not wrong, but to get the same results the filter has to be defined in reversed order.